# Setting text Flow Direction for WPF Localization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, wpflocalizationextension

I am using the [WPF LocalizationExtension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) and could get it work. However, even though it says it has built in support for FlowDirection (righttoleft), I could not get it working and the documentation is not sufficient.

I added the line `FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="{lex:LocText Key=FlowDirection, Dict=Strings, Assembly=LocalizationManager}` in my `<Window ...>` definition. But it throws an error something like `You cannot use "" for Flow Direction`. But if I use the same markup for a text block, I can successfully get the text working `LeftToRight` or `RightToLeft`.

I think it is a type conversion problem, but don't know how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the code as follow and it worked.

```
FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="{lex:LocFlowDirection Key=FlowDirection, Dict=Strings, Assembly=LocalizationManager}"
```